# F# currying .NET standard library functions with multiple parameters?

Tags: .net, f#

According to my book, the standard .NET library functions can have arguments sent via pipelines.

This seems to work for single argument functions but not multiple argument functions, and the book doesn't mention this. I'd like some clarification as to why the following is possible -

```
"hello" |> Directory.GetCreationTime
```

where this is a .NET single parameter function. Whilst the following isn't:

```
"source" |> Directory.Move "dst"
```

where this is a .NET two paramater function.

I understand the .NET Standard Library is built in a non-functional manner not using F#, however it's specifically because the book said that the .NET library could be called using piped functions without specifying that they needed to be single parameter that made me confused.

So I'm curious, is it possible to curry .NET Standard Library functions or not? Can I only call them via pipes if they're a single parameter only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual implementation of the Standard Library methods may differ, but in the specific example you have provided the `Move` function is expecting a `(string*string)`—i.e., a tuple with two strings.

So it is possible to curry the .NET function in this case, it should just be with a tuple. The following will work, albeit it is still technically one parameter:

```ml
("source","dst") |> Directory.Move
```

You can also do something like this to be more consistent with your flow:

```ml
let mapTuple func x y = func(x,y)
"source" |> mapTuple Directory.Move "dst"
```

Comment: I see, thank you! That makes sense. Unfortunately the book made no mention of that but in hindsight it would make sense if non-functional methods could only be called via tuples.

Comment: The rules for arguments are the same for methods and functions. It's just that methods created in C#/VB libraries don't use currying, since these languages don't support currying. You can still create methods in F# that use currying.